# How do I stop hyperref from putting PDF text enhancements in the bookmarks?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, soul

In my book I used a stylized font and background to indicate bits, like this:

[image]

I do that with this macro:

```
\newcommand{\bindigits}[1]{\colorbox{lightlightgray}{\tt{#1}\rm}\xspace}
```

So I thought it would be fun to put my Part numbers in binary, like this:

[image]

Because I couldn't get the `book` style `part` commands to work properly, I wrote my own:

```
\newcommand{\qpart}[3]{%
  \cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part {\bindigits{#1}} #2}

  \thispagestyle{empty}

  \vspace{2in}

  \titlerule[2pt]

  \vspace{2ex}
    \begin{center}
    {\bfseries\Huge Part \bindigits{#1}}\\[2pc]
    {\Huge #2}
    \end{center}

    \titlerule
    \vspace{1em}
    #3
  \cleardoublepage
}
```

And that works really well. I even get the stylized `01` in the table of contents:

[image]

But the PDF bookmarks look like this:

[image]

Which is weird.

Is there any way to fix this, or should I just take the enhancements out of the TOC?

Comment: Search for `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: Very nice. If you want to put this in the answer, I'm fine with that. Otherwise I can answer my own question, but I can't do that for 2 days, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Either you can put `\texorpdfstring` inside the definition of `\bindigits` to provide a replacement text for the bookmarks (font commands changed to LaTeX2e):

```
\newcommand*{\bindigits}[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{\colorbox{lightlightgray}{\texttt{#1}}}{#1}%
    \xspace
}
```

Or the macro `\bindigits` can be redefined for the boomarks:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \renewcommand*{\bindigits}[1]{#1\xspace}%
}
```

Both methods require package `hyperref`.